# Ansible run task only once in an included playbook when looping

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook `test_loop.yml`, which includes another playbook and uses loop, which then includes one more playbook as shown below. I need to run the tasks under `3.yml` only once per `test_loop.yml` execution. I tried like below but `3.yml` contents are getting executed for each iteration of the loop. Any way I can limit the execution of `3.yml` to only once?

`test_loop.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include: one.yml
    loop:
      - 1
      - 2
```

`one.yml`

```
- debug:
    msg: "I'm one.yml item {{ item }}"
- include: 3.yml
```

`3.yml`

```
- debug:
    msg: "I'm a task"
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Any specific reason not to execute 3.yml again? Since it is part of one.yml which runs in a loop, not having to execute 3.yml again defeats the purpose of the loop.

Comment: Yes Saurabh, 3.yml calls scripts to shutdown a database. I cannot shut it down before the loop because other tasks inside the loops won't work if db is down.

Comment: You should consider having a look at [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) eventually combined with [`meta: flush_handlers`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html). That's a perfect candidate for stopping/starting/restarting a db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misinterpreted the meaning of [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once). Its purpose is to run the task a single time **for the batch of hosts in the play** (e.g. iterate over hosts to install a clustered application but run a registration task only once at the end....). It will not stop your loop. Actually, each iteration in the loop is as if your write several tasks with different parameters each time.

In your example, this ends up having your task in `3.yml` being run only for the first host in the play for each iteration (`[1, 2]`), which is precisely what you see.

If you want this task to run only once for your loop, don't loop it. If you want it to run only once for your loop and only for the first host in your play batch, don't loop it and add `run_once` as well.